# color doesn't match in scatter plot

Tags: r, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using highchart, but the color in the graph and in the labels are different. The color should be defined by the column named "Check_color" beacuse i'm using into Rshiny app, and sometimes i don't have all the options in the graph and the color should be align with the column "Rank". I mean, if only "Yes" is selected all points should be green, if only "No", should be red, etc...
Ando Righ now in the graph "Yes" in green, but in the labels are blue, and the same for the rest. How can i math the colors in the labels?    Thanks !!
[image: asaaass]

This is my current code

```
data = data.table(
  CJ(x = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-10"), by = "day"),
     group = seq(1,20))
)

data[, value := round(runif(n=200, 0,5),4)]
data = data.table(data %>% mutate(cat=cut(value, breaks=quantile(data[value!=0]$value, seq(0,1,0.1)), labels=seq(1,10))))

colf = colorRampPalette(colors = c("red","yellow", "green"))
cols = colf(10)

data[, color := as.factor(cols[cat])]
data$x = datetime_to_timestamp(data$x)
data = data.table(data %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y = (order(order(value))-sum(value<0,na.rm=T))))

data[, name := group]
data$x <- runif(200, 100, 1000) / 10
data$y <- runif(200, 100, 1000) / 10

data$gp_ <- round(runif(200,1,5), digits = 0)
data$Index <- seq(1,200,1)

data$Rank <- ifelse(data$gp_ == 1 , "Yes", ifelse(data$gp_ == 2 , "No",ifelse(data$gp_ == 3 , "Minor Deficiency",ifelse(data$gp_ == 4 , "Major Deficiency",ifelse(data$gp_ == 5 , "Not Applicable","")))))

data <- data[1:71,]


data$Check_color <- ifelse(data$Rank == "Yes" , "#14E632", ifelse(data$Rank == "No" , "#FA0101",ifelse(data$Rank == "Minor Deficiency" , "#FF99FF",ifelse(data$Rank == "Major Deficiency" , "#FF9933",ifelse(data$Rank == "Not Applicable" , "#CACECE","")))))

hc_1 <- data %>%
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = x, y = y , group = Rank, color = Check_color  )) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "<b>PUBLIC COMPANY D&O COVERAGE HEAT MAP  </b>") %>%
  hc_chart( 
    borderColor = "#999999",
    borderRadius = 20,
    borderWidth = 3) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = 'Provision ID:  {point.Index} <br/>
                            Provision:  {point.Check_color} <br/>
                            Severity:  {point.y:.2f} <br/>
                            Frequency:  {point.x:.2f} ')


hc_1
```

Comment: (A request: just because you are using this code somewhere in a `shiny` app does not mean that [tag:rshiny] is applicable here. I suggested an edit of removing it, please be mindful of inappropriate tags. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the two color scales came from using `group = Rank` and `color = Check_color` in the hcaes. Remove  `color = Check_color`, and you get matching color. However, I do not know how to specify the color from there... I tried hc_color() which didn't work. Maybe someone else can complete this answer!

```
hc_1 <- data %>%
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = x, y = y , group = Rank  )) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "<b>PUBLIC COMPANY D&O COVERAGE HEAT MAP  </b>") %>%
  hc_chart( 
    borderColor = "#999999",
    borderRadius = 20,
    borderWidth = 3) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = 'Provision ID:  {point.Index} <br/>
                            Provision:  {point.Check_color} <br/>
                            Severity:  {point.y:.2f} <br/>
                            Frequency:  {point.x:.2f} ')


hc_1
```